# C# No overload method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments - simple

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and I came across an error that I don't know how to fix.  As the title states, I get the No overload method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments error.  I have looked at other questions on here but they are more complex then what I am trying to do.  I have a simple equation that I am trying to show in a message box and it looks as follows:

```
Y = C + I + E + G;

MessageBox.Show(ToString(Y));
```

All of the variables in the formula are integers, stored as int, and are taken from text boxes.  I have been learning C# from thenewboston's tutorials on YouTube and I haven't seen this issue there, then again there are over 200 videos on C# and I haven't gotten that far yet.  Any suggestions on error debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I usually use `"" + Y` instead of `Y.ToString()` because the former will result in `""` vs. an `Exception` if `Y` is null. Of course, this might be incorrect (or not required) semantics, so choose appropriately...

Comment: @pst That is interesting to me, wouldn't you want to know as soon as possible if an object that you're working with is null though? Maybe `Y ?? "NULL VALUE"` ?

Comment: @NominSim "It depends" on what should happen. I usually find myself coalescing to "", except when I explicitly want otherwise. Also `Y ?? "foo"` only works when `Y` is a String already. Some people prefer the explicit: `Y != null ? Y.ToString() : ""`. Just things to keep in mind.

Comment: We can't say if the OP declare the var as int? (nullable int) or int. In the second case there is no need to check for nulls

Comment: @pst Ah yes...I meant only that if I am "ignoring" a null value I usually have some "NULL VALUE" default that I would use instead. It definitely all depends on the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
MessageBox.Show(Y.ToString());
```

Comment: /facepalm there.  That fixed my problem, I don't know why I mixed that up, probably thinking in a different language.

Answer (score 13):

The correct syntax is:

```
MessageBox.Show(Y.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

ToString is not an operator.It's a method of the object class.

Comment: Your explanation is completely opaque to someone who's struggling with the correct way to call `ToString()`.

Comment: It is an *instance method*, so it is treated as `MessageBox.Show(this.ToString(Y))`, which might explain it a little better.

Answer (score 3):

To provide a bit of an explanation: In C# everything has a `ToString()` method which you can call to give a string representation of the `Object`. Since you are calling `ToString(Y)`, it complains that you are using the wrong number of arguments for the ToString method. In general, as others have pointed out, the way to represent an object as a `String` is to call `Y.ToString()`.

It is good to note, that you can override the `ToString()` method within any class you make, so that calls to that classes `ToString()` method will return a more useful `String`.

Answer (score 2):

The posts above pretty much covered the solution to your problem. On the error you are getting: 
When you call `ToString(Y)` without referring to a variable, the compiler will look at the current context which in your case is a class which inherits by default from `Object` see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details. So when you do `ToString` the compiler will look at `Object.ToString()` (if not overriden) which takes no parameter and that is why you get:

> No overload method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments error